# SUMO Address Error

Tags: sumo

I'm running multiple SUMO simulations in parallel using TraCI.

Every so often one will fail with the message

```
Error: tcpip::Socket::accept() Unable to create listening socket: Address already in use
Quitting (on error).
```

I haven't found anyway to set the address to use on the configuration list at http://sumo.dlr.de/wiki/SUMO

I figure if I can set each instances address manually I should be able to avoid this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is right on the page you mention. The option --remote-port specifies the port number, so something like

```
sumo --remote-port 54323 -c my.sumocfg
```

should do the trick. Of course you need to give the same port when connecting from your traci client.

Comment: Looks like the simplest way to go is to pass the desired port directly to traci using

    traci.start( sumoCmd, port = 54323)

Interestingly, traci.Start contains

    port = sumolib.miscutils.getFreeSocketPort()

which should have prevented port conflicts in the first place, but I guess its not fool proof